# Reading From HTML5 localstorage json, not recognizing in highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts, local-storage

I have one weird issue, I can put it in points, so that you can understand better.

- please open this fiddle [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/535/) in a browser, As you can see I am using highchart-ng
  https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng angular directive to create the chart. This works fine.
- Now, please open this link also in new tab [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/537/), I have just used the HTML5 localStorage.

  what I am doing is
- First check the chart data in localStorage 'chart', if exists use it, else
- draw the chart from the hard coded json variable $scope.highchartsNG.

What I mean is :

```
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart'))){
        console.log('FROM CACHE');
        $scope.highchartsNG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart'));
}else{
  $scope.highchartsNG = {
            options: {
             ...
             ...
}
```

And for clearing the localStorage I have provided the button

```
<input type='button' onclick='javascript:localStorage.clear();' value='clear localStorage'  />
```

When clicked I am clearing the localStorage with `localStorage.clear();`

Problem is when I read from localstorage , then the chart x-axis and y-axis labels are changed differently, **But how?**

Consider following this steps :

1. when you click on the button 'clear localStorage', then run the fiddle, you will get the proper chart as expected. (That is correct) ok, after that I am storing the data in

   localStorage.setItem('chart', JSON.stringify($scope.highchartsNG));

Now
  2. Again when you run the fiddle it goes inside `if` block and get sthe data from localstorage, then the chart x y axis changed. WHY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see different results is that JSON cannot serialize function (among other things).
So, when you store the object in localStorage, all properties that refer to function (such as formatters) get lost.

---

**UPDATE**:

Just for the fun of it, I impleemnted a simple "serializer" that is able to stringify/parse simple anonymous function (like the ones used in your config).

---

You can see it in action **[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ExpertSystem/Cp73s/554/show/)** (and find the code in this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Cp73s/554/)**).

---

It is not a general purpose, one-size-fits-all, production-ready solution, but it seems to work for your specific case.
Here is a quick overview of how it works:

1. While "stringifying", it first traverses the object and converts each function to string (using its `toString()` method). (Useless tip of the day: This is what Angular uses to recognize injected dependencies, when no inline array notation is used.)
   Then it uses `JSON.stringify` to actually stringify the object.
2. While parsing, it first parses the string as usual (using `JSON.parse`) and then traverses the resulting object, detects string-properties that match a RegExp (designed to match anonymous functions) and finally converts those stringified functions to real functions.

---

Here is the code:

```
.factory('JSONwithFn', function () {
    var fnRE = /^[\s\r\n]*function[\s\r\n]*\([^\)]*\)[\s\r\n]*\{[\s\S]*\}[\s\r\n]*$/i;

    function strToFn(str) {
        var args = str.substring(str.indexOf('(') + 1, str.indexOf(')')).
        split(',').
        map(function (arg) {
            return arg.trim();
        });
        var fnBody = str.substring(str.indexOf('{') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('}')).
        trim();
        args.push(fnBody);
        return Function.apply(null, args);
    }

    function parseFns(obj) {
        var retObj;

        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)) {
            case '[object Undefined]':
            case '[object Null]':
            case '[object Boolean]':
            case '[object Number]':
            case '[object Function]':
                retObj = obj;
                break;
            case '[object String]':
                retObj = fnRE.test(obj) ? strToFn(obj) : obj;
                break;
            case '[object Array]':
                retObj = obj.map(function (value) {
                    return parseFns(value);
                });
                break;
            case '[object Object]':
                retObj = {};
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                    var value = obj[key];
                    retObj[key] = parseFns(value);
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return retObj;
    };

    function stringifyFns(obj) {
        var retObj;

        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)) {
            case '[object Undefined]':
            case '[object Null]':
            case '[object Boolean]':
            case '[object Number]':
            case '[object String]':
                retObj = obj;
                break;
            case '[object Function]':
                retObj = obj.toString();
                break;
            case '[object Array]':
                retObj = obj.map(function (value) {
                    return stringifyFns(value);
                });
                break;
            case '[object Object]':
                retObj = {};
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                    var value = obj[key];
                    retObj[key] = stringifyFns(value);
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return retObj;
    }

    return {
        stringify: function (obj) {
            var obj2 = stringifyFns(obj);
            return JSON.stringify(obj2);
        },
        parse: function (str) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(str);
            return parseFns(obj);
        }
    };
});
```

---

#### How to use:

Just inject it into your controller (or whatever) and use `JSNOwithFn.stringify/parse` instead of `JSON.stringify/parse`.
Nothing else needs to be changed in your code.
It will just work :)

Comment: hey, sorry for the delay, I accepted your answer, but can you please have a look at "production-ready solution, but it seems to work for your specific case." can you make it production ready. Just a request

Comment: Not really, because it depends on what you want and how you are going to use it. Serializing function is not a trivial matter (or else brwosers would have it implemented already). The thing is that you don't need a universal function serializer - you need one the works for your requirements. E.g. my serializer supports anonymous function - if that is OK for you then no problem, but if you pass it a named function, then it will break. It depends on what you want to throw at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Like ExpertSystem said, `JSON.stringify` throws out your formatter function when it serializes.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could store your formatter function separately in the controller, and reassign it after loading the chart options from localstorage.

The top of your controller:

```
$scope.xAxisFormatter = function(){
    return 'Week ' + this.value;
}
```

Your chart options:

```
<snip...>
xAxis: {
          tickInterval: 1,
          allowDecimals: false,
          labels: {
             formatter: $scope.xAxisFormatter
                   }                    
        },
<snip...>
```

When loading from localstorage:

```
$scope.highchartsNG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart'));
$scope.highchartsNG.options.xAxis.labels.formatter = $scope.xAxisFormatter;
```